# how to send the form data to server in json format in ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
function ajax() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    console.log($(this).serializeArray());
    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()));
    return false;
  });
}
```

This is the json data i'm getting:

```
[{"name":"firstName","value":"erere"},{"name":"lastName","value":"rere"},{"name":"emailAddress","value":"eregedfd@gmail.com"},{"name":"password","value":"dfdfd"},{"name":"phoneNumber","value":"989989898"}]
```

How can I send it to the server. What should I include in data in the ajax call?

Comment: where is your ajax call... `.submit()` is not `ajax()` call BTW

Comment: send it like you have them. If you are using php you can json_decode() the data server-side.
Also, you can use $(form).serialize() to get a simple name:value pair to submit to your proccess script

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @user3189357 reply from judder is perfect. Read the http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ page for more info on ajax paramenters

Answer (score 3):

A simple example:

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    $.post( "send.php", $(this).serializeArray())
      .done(function( reply ) {
        alert( "Complete, reply from server: " + reply );
      });

    return false;
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for information on handling callbacks.

Comment: It's whatever you have server side to process the form.

Comment: I wish you could downvote comments, you'll need to give us more information to explain what is wrong. Perhaps an error message, or what line the error is occurring on? As far as I am aware there is no 555 error code in HTTP, are you talking about an email error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'post url'
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(resp){
             //action on successful post
        },
        error: function() {
            //handle error
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with jQuery serializing your form data, try changing the `form.serialize()` to `form.serializeArray()`

Comment: @aRahmanS29 it'd be better to ask @judder first if he meant to use the `.serializeArray` method instead and not just edit it assuming this is true because it might not have been his intent.